# Software to download Google Analytics data

Tags: google-analytics

is there an open source or paid for, off the shelf web based application available which can be downloaded and hosted by a company that then downloads data from Google Analytics from the authrozied GA account on a daily/predefined interval basis for certain list of dimensions and metrics?

We would like to be able to first import all historical data into the database and then schedule the service to run on a scheduled basis to import the data into the database as a top up. What options are available?

Answer (score 3):

Next Analytics (http://www.nextanalytics.com/, commercial) is quite nice (at least used to be last year when I was testing it) - that 's an excel addin, so you'd need to set up a scheduled task on a windows box that downloads your data to excel sheets.

Better suited to your requirements and more "native" is probably Google App Scripts - Google offers a readymade script (I think it's called Google Magic or something - just look for "magic" in the shared libraries) that pulls data from GA accounts. Then you can insert it in a Google Doc, have it sent by email, call another web service to receive the data or, well, other things- apps script (a javacript dialect) is pretty flexible.

Comment: Thanks Eike, are you referring to this with your second option? http://analytics.blogspot.in/2012/08/automate-google-analytics-reporting.html

Comment: Yes. Google has created a shared library ("Google Analytics Report Automation (magic) ") that provides access to GA data. Apps  Script docs are at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/.